# Convertir formato de fecha en Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Tengo un formato de fecha que da un reporte:

> 26/08/2017  10:48:13 a. m.

Ahora necesito que este reporte lo pueda convertir en este formato:

> 20120-06-22 19:10:25-07

Estoy trabajando en angular 8 y esta información la necesito enviar en un `post`.

Comment: Agrega el codigo que has generado hasta ahora, pues solo parece que debes JS para lograr lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que sólo necesitas un pipe de Angular.
Si es así, te dejo la web oficial: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Un ejemplo de uso, podría ser:

```
{{ dateObj | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss-SS' }}
```

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

El **DatePipe** te sirve, dependiendo el caso:

Si solo deseas que se visualice en tu vista sin afectar su formato real, te sirve hacerlo como se expresa en el comentario anterior.

```html
<label>
  {{ myDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss-SS' }}
</label>
```

sin embargo si deseas trabajar con las fechas en ese formato que expresas, es decir enviar la fecha formateada por **post** como veo que expresas, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private miDatePipe: DatePipe) {
    console.log(this.formatearFecha('26/08/2017 10:48:13 a. m.'));
    console.log(this.formatearFecha2('26/08/2017 10:48:13 a. m.'));
  }

  formatearFecha(fecha: string) {
    const fechaArray: any[] = fecha.split(/[\/\s\:]/g);

    // Pasamos fecha a milisegundos
    const milliseconds = Date.UTC(fechaArray[2], fechaArray[1] - 1,
      fechaArray[0], fechaArray[3], fechaArray[4], fechaArray[5]);

    const fechaFormateada = this.miDatePipe.transform(milliseconds, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    return `${fechaFormateada} ${fecha.split(/[\s]/g)[1]}-00`;
  }

  formatearFecha2(fecha: string) {
    const fechaArray: any[] = fecha.split(/[\/\s\:]/g);

    // Pasamos la fecha Date
    const date = new Date(fechaArray[2], fechaArray[1] - 1,
      fechaArray[0], fechaArray[3], fechaArray[4], fechaArray[5]);

    const fechaFormateada = this.miDatePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    return `${fechaFormateada} ${fecha.split(/[\s]/g)[1]}-00`;
  }
}
```

**No logré encontrar una forma más optima a mi parecer, dado que el formato de fecha que muestras no es uno válido. Se puede colocar el formato como desees en el siguiente fragmento del cógido:**

```js
const fechaFormateada = this.miDatePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

**Pero para tu solución si anexaba la hora, por la diferencia horaria no me devolvía la misma hora.**

Puedes observar la documentación relacionada al manejo de las fechas en el siguiente enlace https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date

Espero te sirva